# Can a JavaScript method be called with <<method>>: <<method_param>>?

Tags: javascript, methods, reverse-engineering

I have to reverse-engineer a snippet of JavaScript code and although I know what should happen, it's the first time I see syntax like this and I would like to know what happens. Here is what I have:

```
// @param {function}  a   callback method
function generateUri(a) {

   a: if (some condition) {
     // A
   } else if (other condition) {
     // B
   } else {
     // C
   }
```

**Question:**
What does `a:` mean? The parameter `a` is a method, so does this call the method `a` with `A`, `B` or `C`? If so, can I'd be thankfull for some pointers to where I can read up on how this is valid sytax.

Thanks!

**Edit**:
It does not call the method, says my console, which does not trigger on this:

```
foo = function (my_param) {alert(my_param);}
foo: "hello";
```

Comment: a: is just a label, not a param. it could be called anything valid

Comment: If this question came up in a test.. my ans would have been SyntaxError.. I'm following this for an answer.

Comment: @dandavis: can you elaborate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: @Quentin: learning something... nice!

Comment: answer anyone, so I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which is used as a target for `break` and `continue` statements.

It is unrelated to the function argument with the same name.